# Django template IF ELSE | Error: Could not parse some characters

Tags: python, django, django-models

En la plantilla no if me devuelve error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /test/
>       Could not parse some characters: | {{respuestasProgresion.respuestasCorrectas}}||int

Código en mi template:

```
{% for respuestasProgresion in respuestasProgresion %}
      {% if {{respuestasProgresion.respuestasCorrectas}} == 4 %}
          <p>Aquí va un texto</p>
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

`{{respuestasProgresion.respuestasCorrectas}}` tiene valor de 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julian, tu problema es que intentas colocar una variable dentro de la expresión en la etiqueta usando `{{var}}`

debería quedar así:

```
{% for respuestasProgresion in respuestasProgresion %}
      {% if respuestasProgresion.respuestasCorrectas == 4 %}
          <p>Aquí va un texto</p>
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Saludos.

Comment: gracias majo! Ya ves que soy novato en Django. ; )

Comment: Ánimo! por ahí se empieza!